# Bootstrap Progress Bar | Aria-Now Value set but still blank

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, express, progress-bar, pug

So I've made successfully made the bootstrap progress bar, but even when setting the aria-now value the progress bar just stays empty. What am I missing? Built using jade template engine.

```
div(class='progress bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='45')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aria- tags are just used by screen-readers for people who are unable to read the content of your site.  They don't impact the DOM at all.  The reason it is empty is because you need to wrap your DIV in a `.progress` element, and then give `.progress-bar` it a width property - the `width:60%` is what gives the progress bar its % (sorry I don't know jade)

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to add screen reader data back in you can as per http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Comment: That did it, Thanks. Jade code below as a btw. 

div(class='progress')
    div(class='progress-bar progress-bar-danger active' role='progressbar' style='width:60%') $60,000 / $100,000